# How to enable register_globals on Godaddy

Tags: php, register-globals

I have tried few methods, updating php.ini file with this code:

```
;register_globals = on
;allow_url_fopen = off

memory_limit = 512M
post_max_size = 190M
file_uploads = On
upload_max_filesize = 190M

;expose_php = Off
max_input_time = 120
;variables_order = "EGPCS"
;extension_dir = ./
;upload_tmp_dir = /tmp
;precision = 12
SMTP = relay-hosting.secureserver.net
;url_rewriter.tags = "a=href,area=href,frame=src,input=src,form=,fieldset="


; Only uncomment zend optimizer lines if your application requires Zend Optimizer support

;[Zend]
;zend_optimizer.optimization_level=15
;zend_extension_manager.optimizer=/usr/local/Zend/lib/Optimizer-3.3.3
;zend_extension_manager.optimizer_ts=/usr/local/Zend/lib/Optimizer_TS-3.3.3
;zend_extension=/usr/local/Zend/lib/Optimizer-3.3.3/ZendExtensionManager.so
;zend_extension_ts=/usr/local/Zend/lib/Optimizer_TS-3.3.3/ZendExtensionManager_TS.so


; -- Be very careful to not to disable a function which might be needed!
; -- Uncomment the following lines to increase the security of your PHP site.

;disable_functions = "highlight_file,ini_alter,ini_restore,openlog,passthru,
                      phpinfo, exec, system, dl, fsockopen, set_time_limit,
                      popen, proc_open, proc_nice,shell_exec,show_source,symlink"
[browscap]
browscap = /home/content/b/o/o/boombastic/extra/php_browscap.ini
```

and nothing seems to work. I have talked to their support and they don't want to enable it. I have it working on bluehost and i believe its enabled there by default.

Comment: So, leaving it commented out doesn't help, huh? But do even you know what register_globals are for? What's the code making it necessary? Why not follow the `extract()` examples from le manual instead?

Comment: Do not use `register_globals = On` first of all, that is a big security hole, and 2nd, `This feature has been DEPRECATED as of PHP 5.3.0 and REMOVED as of PHP 5.4.0.`

Comment: The last time I did any serious stuff with PHP was over a decade ago… and even then "Don't use register globals" was rule 1. Fix your PHP so it doesn't need register globals.